# Android application which you cannot close

Tags: android

Is there any programming tricks that makes your application unclosable?

For example: You touch the back or the home button, but they don't do anything. 
Or at least is there a way that your application blocks some applications to open?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can stop user from moving your application to background unless it's some `kiosk mode app`. And the method to do that is to become device administrator and override all possible callback methods - `home, back, settings, notification area etc`.

If you just want to prevent your app from getting closed due to user activity you can show a `persistent notification`. This will allow you app to run in background even if user presses home button.

Answer (score 0):

Make a launcher/Home screen app:

- When users click the home button, your app will show.
- You control ALL apps that can be started

Answer (score 0):

On devices running android lolipop, you can use the screen pinning option available in your ROM.

**NOTE: This is ROM feature, you don't have to do anything in your app.**

See this great [article](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/ho-to-pin-apps-in-android-5-lollipop/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

yes its to get set the on backpressed method to.

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hack in android OS ? Let me tell you that android apps are sandboxed, which isolates your app data and code execution from other apps.